# Developing an API using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api

I have some questions in the below code.I would really appreciate if someone could break it down. 
I am trying to build a simple `helloworldAPI`. Below is the code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');

//configuring the app for the bosy data intake for post operations
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Configuring the app to listen to the PORT
var PORT= process.env.PORT || 3000;

//connectivity to the DB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/helloworldapi');

//API Routes
var router = express.Router();

//Routes will be prefixed with /API

app.use('/api', router);

//Test route
router.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.json({message: 'Welcome to our API'});

});
app.listen(PORT);
console.log('server listening on port '+PORT);
```

The code snippets that I would need help here are:

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));` here, what does `extended: true` mean?

`var PORT= process.env.PORT || 3000;` what does `process.env.PORT` do? I haven't set any port numbers in my environment variables.

`app.use('/api', router);` : What does this do? Does this have to do something with the resources of the API?

`router.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.json({message: 'Welcome to our API'});` : How does the API call route to the reply message here? I am not clear why `/` is used in the get method.

And the last question: Why is the API having a separate listening PORT. I have set up mongoDB, which listens to the port `27017`. I know the API gateway has a separate port that it listens to but should it be hard coded while using nodeJS? Because I have worked with ESBs and exposing them as APIs on WSO2. The API gateway uses a default port 9443 there. Why should it be 3000 here?

Comment: All of those questions are easily answered by googling around a bit. Read the Docs for Express

Comment: Hi @Luca. Appreciate your reply. I have tried googling them. But i learnt about the code snippets but not as a whole process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```

> here, what does extended: true mean?

The `extended` option for the body-parser middleware is documented [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#extended).  It determines which library is used to parse the query string and whether embedded objects are supported in the query string or not.  Read the doc for more details.  That option is probably not relevant to you if you're not trying to do something really advanced with query strings.

---

```
var PORT= process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

> what does process.env.PORT do? I haven't set any port numbers in my environment variables.

This selects the port to run your server on.  If there is a `PORT=xxx` in your environment, it will use that number.  If not, it will use `3000`.

---

```
app.use('/api', router);
```

> What does this do? Does this have to do something with the resources of the API?

This loads a router (that would typically define a bunch of route handlers) and makes its root path that the routes serve start with `/api`.  This defines the URLs that the API will support and hooks the code up to each one.  So, if you had `/api/users`, then the router would define the `/users` route and this statement would put that all under `/api` to make the route be `/api/users`.

---

```
router.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.json({message: 'Welcome to our API'});
});
```

> How does the API call route to the reply message here? I am not clear why / is used in the get method.

Assuming this is inside the previously mentioned router, this defines the response for `/api`.  Since this router is mounted at `/api` by the previous code piece `app.use('/api', router);`, the `/` route would just be `/api`.  If you used `router.get('/users', ...)`, then the route would be `/api/users`.

`router.get(...)` means that it's a route definition for a GET request.  Just like `router.post(...)` is a route definition for a POST request.

---

> And the last question: Why is the API having a separate listening PORT.

The API shown here is a web server.  All servers must listen on a port.  Your database is its own server that listens on its own port.  For anyone to use an API, they must know its port so it is not surprising that it is coded that way it is.  It isn't really hard-coded.  A default value is hard coded, but it can be easily modified without changing the code by just setting an environment variable before running the server.  In any case, anyone attempting to use the API has to know what host and port it's running on since all connections to a server require an IP address and a port.

---

> Why should it be 3000 here?

3000 is a popular port number that is not pre-assigned to any standard services.  You can pick any port number that is not pre-assigned to some sort of well-known service and does not conflict with anything else running on your server.  The range between 3000 and 9999 are often used for this kind of thing, but in the IANA port registry, there are lots of port numbers that are not specified for a particular service that you can choose.